# Increase frequency of status messages from UR5

Tags: control, robotic-arm

I know the UR5 is sending me messages with its status (I can't yet understand them though, but I'm already working on that).  However, they are too far apart to be useful: It sends them every 0.1 s.  I would like that to be at least every 0.01 s.  How can I change that configuration?

Comment: Actually I found out that the robot is not able to follow commands (through a TCP socket) that are closer in time than 100 ms, so probably it is limited to that frequency.

Comment: @jsotola I relatively know what they contain, because I've seen a screen of ROS (from a a friend) which tells info about the robot such as state, position, velocity, ... , and it makes sense with the bytes I read (some of them change when the robot moves).  It's just that I don't know the exact structure of the bytes, but I know what they are more or less.  But if the robot is not prepared to interpret orders faster than 10 Hz, then I don't see any usefulness in knowing it's state with 1 kHz.  If I could also modify the speed at which it can interpret commands, that would be useful, though.

Comment: ok, that makes good sense